# Convergence of a non explicit sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was wondering if someone could help me prove this: Let $\lbrace a_n \rbrace$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with ${a_n} \rightarrow a $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. If $a>0$ prove that there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n>0$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: Use the definition of the limit.  As $n$ gets large, the points must cluster around smaller and smaller neighborhoods of $a$.  Since $a > 0$, then after some point, the members of the sequence must be too.  Now put all this into formal math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a \gt 0$, then, for example, $\frac a2$ is

- $\gt 0$
- at positive distance $\frac a2$ from $a$.

So, there exists ...